# Can we make Whats Your Favorite Programmer Cartoon permantly open and unable to close?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

This is the [most famous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556) on Stackoverflow and should have a protected status.

Can we make this impossible to close?

Comment: I think you'll probably find that some people feel the exact opposite and want it to remain closed permanently. (I'm not one of them)

Comment: I think closing/opening should grow based on how many times. First time 5 to close 5 to open, second 10-10, third, 20-20. Eventually, if the public likes it enough, it will stay open.

Comment: I actually wonder if voting to close shouldn't be allowed on a higher rep value.

Comment: if we do change the rep value, please add this line. (Rep="4000" OR User_Name = "Chacha102")

Comment: @Chacha102: It's going to be terribly difficult for people to keep their rep at exactly 4000 so they're able to vote to close.

Comment: That question needs to be burned, its ashes buried, and the ground in which it is laid salted so nothing can ever grow there again.

Comment: That questions is endlessly used as "justification" of why all manner of other off-topic stuff should be allowed. I'm fond of it, but wouldn't shed a tear if it was sent to /dev/null

Comment: Touche Pesto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Absolutely not.  Why would you want to subvert the community's decision, whatever it may be?  Also, I'd argue that the question is more infamous than famous.

Answer (score 4):

It's fun to have a limited number of "fun" questions. The problem is that they set a bad example. They serve as an excuse for more "fun" questions.

I mostly think these should be subject to the will of the community. My "will" is likely to be to close them. However, a good fun question is likely to be reopened. In fact, over its life, I think it's likely to go through several close/reopen cycles, and maybe even close/delete/undelete/reopen. That makes it a *really* bad example.

I propose that we create a special site for those, maybe fun.stackoverflow.com. What's really special about this site would be that it does not accept new questions. Instead, a moderator may manually migrate a surviving "fun" question (after six months, say), from SO to FSO. We'd be able to add new answers to the question, but it would be off of SO, and the front page of SO, and would stop being a bad example.

Comment: +1 Not a bad idea, although I am not to sure if it will happen.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fine with it being open to new answers, as long as it stays off the front page.  I've often seen it pop up again when someone adds a new answer and I clicked the "active" tab.

Comment: I was just going to mention the same thing. Is there a good way to keep it off of the front page? I can't think of any specific rule that wouldn't allow gaming.

Comment: How about CW questions over a week old?  I can't think of one that I want to see everytime I log in.  I can always add it to my favorites if I want to follow it.

Comment: I think after 2 weeks, questions should stay off the home page unless a bounty is added.